# Password and confirm password don't match

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a password and confirm password field like below.

[image]

I have used the same elements and script in 2 other different forms, but it isn't working in one of the forms.

```js
var password = document.getElementById('pwd'), confirm_password = document.getElementById('cpwd');
    function validatePassword() {
        if (password.value != confirm_password.value) {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity('Passwords Don\'t Match');
        } else {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
    password.onchange = validatePassword;
    confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
  <input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" class="validate" minlength="8" required="">
  <label for="pwd" data-error="Please enter a name of length minum 8 characters" data-success="Perfect!">Desired Password<span class="red-text">&nbsp;*</span></label>
</div>
                    
<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
  <input id="cpwd" name="cpwd" type="password" class="validate"  required="">
  <label for="cpwd" data-error="Please enter the same password again" data-success="Perfect!">Confirm password<span class="red-text">&nbsp;*</span></label>
</div>


  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do the trim of both psword first and then validate.

Comment: Please elaborate on "isn't working". What's supposed to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: aside: use the `inp.oninput` event instead of key and change events

Comment: validate works only for one form in the page or at least you have differen classes to get values, and or you are using one id multiple time i a page. I had a div with multiple forms generated from database with the same form input classes and I got same issues. the I changed the code to have only one visible form for page, other forms I made hidden. jquery doesn;t validate hidden input values. 
I was able though validate forms and hide them when I moved to next form.

Comment: Does it match when you type one more character in the `confirm_password` (e.g. `"password1"`? Then it's probably because you invoke `validate()` with `.onkeyup`, and the character hasn't actually been inputted into the `<input>` by that time, so the value hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: try to console log before validating if you got whole input

Comment: Wait, do you mean you have multiple forms on one page, all with exactly the same HTML as above, so also all with `id="pwd"` and `id="cpwd"`? You can't do that. I wouldn't go for @Janatbek's solution (I would use classes on the elements, and `this` this inside the function so that all elements can use the same function without chance of interference), but he's certainly right that you can't use the same `id` twice on one page

Comment: they had same classes, not id's. You can't use more then once id. In my comment above I say maybe you have same id twice per page and it is causing conflict

Comment: @myfunkyside Not on the same page. In console it shows, password matches

Comment: Try this using simple code first without all this mess and that would help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @RobertRocha You're right. This works perfect when it is run separate from the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was just a class conflict in the remaining script and there was no issue as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
Password: <input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password"><br><br>
Conform Password: <input id="cpwd" name="cpwd" type="password">
<div id="errorMsg"></div>
<script>
var password = document.getElementById('pwd');
confirm_password = document.getElementById('cpwd');
    function validatePassword() {
        if ((confirm_password.value!='')&&(password.value != confirm_password.value)) {
            document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML='Passwords Don\'t Match';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML='';
        }
    }
    password.onchange = validatePassword;
    confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `keyup` or `change` event, I would suggest listening to the `input` event.

From [the relevant article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

> The DOM `input` event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.

```js
var password = document.getElementById('pwd'),
  confirm_password = document.getElementById('cpwd');

function validatePassword() {
  if (password.value !== confirm_password.value) {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
  } else {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
password.oninput = validatePassword;
confirm_password.oninput = validatePassword;
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
  <input id="pwd" name="pwd" type="password" class="validate" minlength="8" required="">
  <label for="pwd" data-error="Please enter a name of length minum 8 characters" data-success="Perfect!">Desired Password<span class="red-text">&nbsp;*</span></label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12 m6">
  <input id="cpwd" name="cpwd" type="password" class="validate" required="">
  <label for="cpwd" data-error="Please enter the same password again" data-success="Perfect!">Confirm password<span class="red-text">&nbsp;*</span></label>
</div>
```